# Run command in CMD via python and extract the data

Tags: python, list, cmd, subprocess, extract

I am trying to use the below code to run a command and extract the data from the cmd.

the file with the commands and data is a txt file.  (let me know if I should change it or use an excel if better).

the commands look something like this: ping "host name" which would result in some data in the cmd.there is list of these in the file. so it would ping "hostname1" then line two ping "hostname2"..etc

**THE QUESTION:** I want it to run every line individually and extract the results from the cmd and store them in a txt file or excel file - Ideally I want all the results in the same file. is this possible? and how?

here is the code so far:

```
root_dir = pathlib.Path(r"path to file here")
cmds_file = root_dir.joinpath('actual file here with commands and data') 
#fail = []
cmds = cmds_file.read_text().splitlines()

try:

for cmd in cmds:
    args = cmd.split() 
    print(f"\nRunning: {args[0]}")
    output = subprocess.check_output(args)


    print(output.decode("utf-8"))
    out_file = root_dir.joinpath(f"Name of file where I want results printed in")
    out_file.write_text(output.decode("utf-8"))
except:
pass
```

Comment: Why don't you juste use a redirection after your command ?
`YourCommand > YourFile.txt`

Comment: Not quite sure how to go about that but will look into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My plan is simple:

1. Open input, output file
2. Read input file line by line
3. Execute the command and direct the output to the output file

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import pathlib
import shlex
import subprocess

cmds_file = pathlib.Path(__file__).with_name("cmds.txt")
output_file = pathlib.Path(__file__).with_name("out.txt")
with open(cmds_file, encoding="utf-8") as commands, open(output_file, "w", encoding="utf-8") as output:
    for command in commands:
        command = shlex.split(command)
        output.write(f"\n# {shlex.join(command)}\n")
        output.flush()
        subprocess.run(command, stdout=output, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, encoding="utf-8")
```

## Notes

- Use `shlex.split()` to simulate the bash shell's command split
- The line `output.write(...)` is optional. You can remove it
- With `subprocess.run(...)`, the `stdout=output` will redirect the command's output to the file. You don't have to do anything.

## Update

I updated the `subprocess.run` line to redirect stderr to stdout, so error will show.

Comment: Absolutely amazing, quick follow up. sometimes pinging hosts can result in an error. I dont want the process to stop and I want the ping (host name) that didnt work to still be output-ed in the file - perhaps with the error message it received. is that possible?

Comment: Just another follow, i am going to incorporate what you said into what I have so far and if it works I will cry.

Comment: hello Hai! thank you so much your code worked but I wanted to ask you is there a way to do it without the run command as I believe it is causing some slowness in the code? thank you again

Comment: It is not the `subprocess.run` function that causes slowness, but the IP addresses which are not ping'able. We can speed this up by using `concurrent.futures` to ping several IPs concurrently, but that is the topic for another time.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a module called subprocess `import subprocess`

Then you can define a variable like this
`run = subprocess.run(command_to_execute, capture_output=True)`

After that you can do `print(run.stdout)` to print the command output.
If you want to write it to a file you can do this after you run the above code

```
    with open("PATH TO YOUR FILE", "w") as file:
        file.write(run.stdout)
```

This should write a file which contains the output of your command
After that close the file using `file.close()` and reopen it but in "a" mode

```
    with open("PATH TO YOUR FILE", "a") as file:
        file.write(\n + run.stdout)
```

This should append data to your file.
Remember to close the file just for best practice, I have some bad memorys about not closing the file after I opened it :D

Comment: Would this work for every line of command, as in, would it write the data to to the file for each line? - especially if I have it in the for loop? - thanks btw I am fairly new at this.

Comment: @JuniorData I'm not sure, it should work but note. Only use file.write() for your first command after that use file.close() to close the file again and reopen it the same way but not in "w" but in "a" mode so you can append data to your file. After you opend the file again you can just write like shown above and it will add the data to your file